# How to filter MySQL SELECT by an aggregate function?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT h11, HA11
FROM florin.h11
WHERE (3>d1 AND 3<d2) OR (3>d1 AND 3=d2 AND id=MAX(id))
UNION (3=d1 AND 3<d2 AND id=MIN(id));
```

Here a screenshot of my table stucture:
[image]

Comment: There's more than one thing wrong with your query. You can't use `MAX` the way you use it, and you can't use `UNION` without another `SELECT`. Please edit your question to describe exactly what you want the query to produce.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is your expected output?

Comment: `3>d1 AND 3<d2` - argh I hate this idiom - it makes much more sense reading `d1 < 3 AND d2 > 3`

Comment: Who named your columns?  Are they masochists?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you would like to do is something like this:

```
SELECT h11, HA11
FROM florin.h11 
WHERE (3>d1 AND 3<d2) 
   OR (3>d1 AND 3=d2 AND id = (SELECT MAX(t2.id) 
                               FROM florin.h11 AS t2))
   OR (3=d1 AND 3<d2 AND id = (SELECT MIN(t3.id)
                               FROM florin.h11 AS t3));
```

Comment: Why do you use the `UNION` instead of another `OR`?

Comment: because there was a union in the original query, but it doesn't make much sense, now that i have a closer look...

Answer (score 0):

First wrong thing is

- Please mention if, florin is database and h11 is table.

If florin is table then write only "select h11,HA11 from florin", don't write column name.

Second wrong thing is

- Union operator is used to join results of two query. For more info surf www.w3school.com

So, fire query like

```
select h11, HA11 
from florin 
where (3 > d1 and 3 < d2) or (3 > d1 and 3 = d2 and id = MAX(id))

union 

select h11, HA11 
from florin 
where (3 = d1 and 3 < d2 and id = MIN(id))
```

Here may this query doesn't return desired result but this was my imagine that you want such type of query.

Comment: Third wrong thing is you probably want a subselect where you are using max(id), but I cannot tell what your goal is.